# Countdown timer iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, timer, countdown

I have a countdown timer in my game and I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that it shows        two decimal places and records with 2 decimal places in my table.  Right now it counts down as a whole number and records as a whole number.  Any ideas?

```
-(void)updateTimerLabel{

     if(appDelegate.gameStateRunning == YES){

                            if(gameVarLevel==1){
       timeSeconds = 100;
       AllowResetTimer = NO;
       }
    timeSeconds--;
    timerLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %d", timeSeconds];
}

    countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimerLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have sub-second updates, the timer's interval needs to be < 1. But the precision of NSTimer is just around 50 ms, so `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01` will not work.

Moreover, the timer can be delayed by various activities, so using `timeSeconds` will lead to inaccurate timing. The usual way is compare the NSDate now with the date when the timer starts. However, as this code is for a game, the current approach may cause less frustration to players esp. if the program or background processes consumes lots of resources.

---

The first thing to do is to convert the countdownTimer to sub-second interval.

```
countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.67 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimerLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Then, don't count down the time by seconds, but centiseconds:

```
if(appDelegate.gameStateRunning == YES){
   if(gameVarLevel==1){
      timeCentiseconds = 10000;
      AllowResetTimer = NO;
   }
}
timeCentiseconds -= 67;
```

Finally, divide by 100 in the output:

```
timerLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %d.%02d", timeCentiseconds/100, timeCentiseconds%100];
```

---

Alternatively, use a `double`:

```
double timeSeconds;
...
if(appDelegate.gameStateRunning == YES){
   if(gameVarLevel==1){
      timeSeconds = 100;
      AllowResetTimer = NO;
   }
}
timeSeconds -= 0.67;
timerLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %.2g", timeSeconds];
```

Comment: I want the countdown to have two decimal places...and count down like 119.99, 119.98, 119.97...

Comment: @NextRev: To switch from 119.99 to 119.98 does it take 1 second or 0.01 seconds?

Comment: timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %02d", timeSeconds]; doesn't give me any decimal points

Comment: i got it working thanks.  do you know how i have it show up as a decimal in my sqlite table?  it's still showing up as a whole number.

Comment: @NextRev: You can store as a `double`, but I'd say *don't care*. The users will be unlikely to reach the SQLite table and complain you're using an integer instead of floating point numbers.

Comment: actually a mode in my game is timed so hundredths of a second could matter

Comment: @NextRev: No, I mean by switching to `timeCentiseconds` each unit already corresponds to 0.01 seconds. e.g. the whole number 19998 means 199.98 seconds in the UI.

Comment: oh ok, but what field type do i use so that it shows up with a decimal in my high scores menu?

Comment: @NextRev: You need to format the integer 19999 into 199.99 every time you need to display the number. Also, if you don't mind precision lost, you can use a `double` for the `timeSeconds`, and use `timeSeconds -= 0.67;` in the count-down. (See update.)

Comment: it's only showing a .0 in the sqlite table.  if the end result was 78.21 it's only showing 78.0

Comment: @NextRev: How do you insert the result to the SQLite table?

Comment: else if(easymediumhard == 2){
   sql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into tblHard(Score) values (?)"];